# How to compare a field with another in Mongodb aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have pipeline many level in, Now I would like to compare two fields like follow:

```js
db.collection.aggregate({ ...},
{$match:{firstfield:{$gte:"$secondfield"}}})
```

How to write this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close but the actual invocation is slightly different:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "firstfield": 1,
        "secondfield": 1,
        "difference": { "$gte": [ "$firstfield", "$secondfield" ] }
    }},
    { "$match": { "difference": true } }
])
```

So a bit different to the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) invocation, the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) ( or possibly [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) ) form allow for a `true|false` value to be returned on the field comparison.

This allows you to filter with the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) phase later in the pipeline in order to "include|exclude" results based on the logical condition that was projected.

Comment: Of course it does. Your acceptance and up-vote are appreciated, as always :)